# Возвращение функцией результата выполнения getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Нужно вывести результат, полученный при getJSON
Пробовал два варианта. первый, как я понял, не работает из-за асинхронности

```
function synchronize(){
    var json;
    $.getJSON(data_url, function(data){
        json = data;
    });
    return json;
}
console.log(synchronize());
```

Вот второй

```
function synchronize(){
    $.getJSON(data_url, function(data){
        return data;
    });
}
console.log(synchronize());
```

Comment: @Grundy, очень неудачный ответ на этот вопрос, а его везде пихают как пример реализации, может всё таки добавить где-нибудь такой же ответ, только без примесей chrome-extension, а то эти примеси делают код очень сложным для понимания...

Comment: @MasterAlex, если абстрагироваться от названия _chrome_, то в том вопросе такая же функция с коллбэком, и решение абсолютно одинаковое. не важно как именно называется функция и из какого объекта она вызывается

Comment: @Grundy, ну вообще кроме `chrome` там ещё есть параметры функции, которые нужны для этого `chrome-extenstion`, но совершенно не нужны всем остальным спрашивающим, эти параметры перемешиваются в вызове, также используются в ответе функции и получается код, сильно сложнее чем есть на самом деле. Думаю авторы многих подобных вопросов так и не поняли что за ссылку им дали и как она им поможет.

Comment: @MasterAlex, стоит спросить об этом у авторов

Comment: Я все понял, спасибо за ссылку :D